# PF vs -m of iptables

Tags: iptables, pf

As you know, iptables has `-m (match)` such as :

```
-m string 
-m state 
-m -iplimit 
and so on...
```

My question: Does `PF` has similar features such as `-m` of `iptables`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, `pf` does not have the flexibility and modules available in `iptables`. `iptables` comes with really large number of modules that provide more match options and others that provide more targets. You can even develop your own module. [This page](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-4.html) provides some explanation regarding iptables development if you are interested.

Comment: I have a serious question: i didn't any doc accordint to develop module, Can you give me a link?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: Are you asking about a link for iptables module development?

Comment: No, pf development, You said: > You can even develop your own module

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: I am talking about iptables. I did not find any reference about `pf` modules/plugins or something similar.